# python, aws S3 download zip file

Tags: boto

I am trying to download a .zip file from AWS S3 using boto code, however getting following error:

'str' object has no attribute 'write'

**code**

```
s3Conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id='ABCD',
                      aws_secret_access_key='xyz')
s3bucket = s3Conn.get_bucket(mybucket)

key = s3bucket.new_key("2015/02/20/TestFile.zip")  
try:
    key.get_contents_to_file(backupdir)
except:
    print("{0}".format(sys.exc_info()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `backupdir` is string but boto expects file object (like `open(backupdir)` )

Comment: You can use ``get_contents_to_filename`` with a string path but it needs to be a fully-qualified path, not just a path to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
def downloadBackupFile(backupdir):
    key = s3bucket.new_key("2015/02/20/TestFile.zip")
    try:
        if (os.path.exists(backupdir)):
        key.get_contents_to_file(open(backupdir + "TestFile.zip", "w+"))
    except:
        print("{0}".format(sys.exc_info()))
```